# DataTables going to last page on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using the old DataTables (ie: `var oTable = $('#example').dataTable()`) and using `oTable.fnPageChange('last');` to go to the last page when the table loads. The problem is, I've tried it in `"fnInitComplete"` function or also outside of the DataTable initialization and in the `document.ready()` instead, but the best case the table goes to the last page but the rows are actually from the first page.

It seems as if it is trying to go to the last page before the ajax call is finished. The reason is because if I place a form button which runs `oTable.fnPageChange('last');` it works.

I can't use the newer `table.page('last')` because it conflicts with some of my other code.

Thanks!

Comment: where is the code? what are you asking?

Comment: I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevmor/qL0p61wo/3/) but it works... some reason my code is showing the last page selected but the data in the table is still on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `bServerSide` set to `true` was causing the problem...